# Android 12: Layout is not properly displayed when using startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-12, startactivityforresult

I'm migrating a android app from target SDK 30 to 31:

```
    compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion '31.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "some.app.id"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode xyz
    versionName "xyz"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

There is one activity that behaves differently depending on how it is opened:

- startAcitity: The Acitivity works as expected
- startActivityForResult: The UI is not working properly (elements dont appear after programatically changing their visibility, the button size is not adapted to its content anymore but a fixed size is set)

After some tests, the problem seems to be related to the resizing of the UI. Its not happening anymore. Buttons are not resized based on its content, elements set to GONE still take the space etc.

Anyone else came across this issue?

Comment: Can you show the XML code?

Comment: I added the layout of the activity and provided 2 examples where the layout is not working properly.

Comment: First of all tools:layout_editor_absoluteX or any other tools are just for Android Studio. It won't reflect when you run the app. So maybe start from there.

Comment: The question is why this problem only occurs with startActivityForResult and not with startAcitity. If the problem would be related to  tools:layout_editor_absoluteX, it should happen in both cases, right?
I guess there could be a problem that some of my dependencies are not working with SDK31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue in a new project without success.

Eventually I found that this problem occured due to changes to the UI in the wrong thread:
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Running the code in "runOnUiThread" solved the issue.